# Jetpack compose: Relay plugin - the composable file is not being generated

Tags: android, relayjs, figma

I want to use the relay plugin in order to convert a figma component into a composable file in Android Studio.

1. I followed all the steps in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/relay/install-relay#install-relay
2. I have all the prerequisites version wise.  (I am signed into a Figma Account + .
   Android Studio 2022.2.1 Flamingo or later + Java Runtime+  Jetpack Compose version 1.2 or later + using Gradle Plugin version 8.0 or later)
3. In Android Studio, I imported the Figma component( file-> new -> import UI packages) and I see in "ui-pacakges" all the generated files by the plug in.
4. Everything is working by the manual - including the  generated json file

   {
   "target": "ListItem",
   "package": "com.google.samples.apps.nowinandroid.feature.interests.listitem",
   "generateImplementation": true,
   "generatePreviews": true
   }
5. I build the project -> The build runs successfully -> I run "Reload from Disk" but there is no composable generated file in my folder.

The whole process works well - besides the actual product that I need: the actual composable

Any thoughts? Does someone have a solution for this? Thanks.